# Is there a way to format the width of a substring within a string in a bash/sh script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have to format the width of a substring within a string using a bash script, but without using tokens or loops. A single character between two colons should be prepended by a 0 in order to match the standard width of 2 for each field.

For e.g

from:

```
6:0:36:35:30:30:72:6c:73:0:c:52:4c:30:31:30:31:30:30:30:31:36:39:0:1:3
```

to

```
06:00:36:35:30:30:72:6c:73:00:0c:52:4c:30:31:30:31:30:30:30:31:36:39:00:01:03
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What does "without tokens" mean?

Comment: What to do with a substring like abc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/\<([0-9a-f])\>/0\1/g'
```

Search and replace with a regex. Use `\<` and `\>` to match word boundaries so `[0-9a-f]` only matches single digits.

```
$ sed -r 's/\<([0-9a-f])\>/0\1/g' <<< "6:0:36:35:30:30:72:6c:73:0:c:52:4c:30:31:30:31:30:30:30:31:36:39:0:1:3"
06:00:36:35:30:30:72:6c:73:00:0c:52:4c:30:31:30:31:30:30:30:31:36:39:00:01:03
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(length($i)==1)gsub($i,"0&",$i)}1' file
```

Output:

```
06:00:36:35:30:30:72:6c:73:00:0c:52:4c:30:31:30:31:30:30:30:31:36:39:00:01:03
```

This will divide the whole line into fields separated by `:` , if the length of any of the field is `==` 1. then it will replace that field with `0`field.

Answer (score 0):

Bash solution:

```sh
IFS=:; for i in $string; do echo -n 0$i: | tail -c 3; done
```

Answer (score 0):

With

```
str="06:00:36:35:30:30:72:6c:73:00:0c:52:4c:30:31:30:31:30:30:30:31:36:39:00:01:03"
```

you can add a '0' to all tokens and remove those that are unwanted:

```
sed -r 's/0([0-9a-f]{2})/\1/g' <<< "0${str//:/:0}"
```

That doesn't feel right, making errors and repairing them.

A better alternative is

```
echo $(IFS=:; printf "%2s:" ${str} | tr " " "0")
```